# Acessing Meta ordering from relational model in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to access 'Meta' ordering from ForeignKey relational model and couldn't make it work. following are the models and I need to get ordering of submodel to function of parent model. I can access ordering for Product or Product image in shell but cannot do it with relational submodel. Please advise.

```
Product(models.Model): #parent model
  ....
class Meta:
  ordering = ['-date_created']
  def primary_image(self):
      images = self.images.all()
      ordering = self.images.model._meta.ordering #Just need to get order of submodel Meta here.

ProductImages(models.Model): #submodel and images with related name "images".
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.Product', related_name='images', verbose_name=_("Product"))
    original = models.ImageField(
        _("Original"), upload_to=settings.MARKET_IMAGE_FOLDER, max_length=255)
    caption = models.CharField(_("Caption"), max_length=200, blank=True)

    #: Use display_order to determine which is the "primary" image
    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _("Display order"), default=0,
        help_text=_("An image with a display order of zero will be the primary"
                    " image for a product"))
    class Meta:
    ordering = ('display_order')

Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  135.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  210.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1197.                     return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mudassar\supermarekt\market\catalogue\templatetags\product_tags.py" in render_product
  28.     return template_.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  212.                 return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  56.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  56.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  574.                   six.iteritems(self.extra_context)}
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in <dictcomp>
  573.         values = {key: val.resolve(context) for key, val in
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  648.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  789.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  849.                             current = current()
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\amazonclone\market\catalogue\models.py" in primary_image
  404.         ordering = self.images.model.Meta.ordering

Exception Type: AttributeError at /offer/
Exception Value: type object 'ProductImage' has no attribute 'Meta'
```

Comment: What was the error you got? What you tried is the same as what I would have tried...

Comment: In one of my previous project I used Meta and it worked but not in this case I don't know why. I've updated the question with traceback. But if I use _meta it throws symlink error as I am on windows. os.symlink may not work on Windows.

Comment: Your traceback is inconsistent with your code, the traceback says `self.images.Meta.ordering` and your code said `self.images.model._meta.ordering`. I think the latter is correct.

Comment: I used _meta in the code but it is not allowing me to post the code with error with message that it includes most of the code etc etc. Let me fix it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

> By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta.

So you don't need to access it at all, they use this ordering already.

If you're looking to apply the related models ordering as part of the other model, you should be able to include it in the list of ordering

```
ordering = ['-date_created', 'images']
```

Comment: Parent model has it's own ordering with ordering=('-date_created'). So I am confused here would it really apply both?

Comment: @Alikhan - What happened when you tried it? what does the parent's ordering have to do with the given queryset?

Comment: It says "type object 'ProductImage' has no attribute 'Meta'".

Comment: @Alikhan - I meant when you tried retrieving the images as above. Again, you don't need to access the meta.

Comment: Again I am trying to access submodel Meta class ordering in parent model function.

Comment: you are correct and it has to be like this. But it throws Attribute error on particular line where I tried to access Meta. So if you can give me a clue I will be able to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Sayes once again you rock man. You were right to use multiple features to be added for ordering in parent class. It works.